When using sns.heatmap and correlation (corr), it is not possible to display all values
How to make the values appear on all cells and not only in the first row?
It should be like this
enter image description here
But it turns out like this
enter image description here
Here is the code I use:
df.corr(numeric_only=True)

enter image description here
plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
sns.heatmap(df.corr(numeric_only=True), cmap="RdBu", annot=True, annot_kws={"fontsize":10})
plt.title('Таблиця кореляції')
plt.show()

